# What is the rank of the rating in which maximum movies fell into?

Tags: mysql, sql, rank

Hi i have the following data model.

[image]

I need to find the rank of the rating in which maximum movies fell into.
I have written the following query which my trainer tells me is wrong.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT r.movieratingid) AS rank
FROM
  Rating r JOIN movie m ON r.movieratingid = m.rating_movieratingid
GROUP BY count(distinct r.movierating)
HAVING count(m.movieid) = (SELECT sum(m1.movieid) from movie m1
Where m.movieid = m1.movieid)
```

Please tell me what is wrong in the above query.

---

- movie table

---

[image]

---

- ratings table

---

[image]

Comment: can you give sample records with your desired result?

Comment: my trainer has told me not to create a db and test it i have to analyse the data model and only write the query

Comment: that data model is very big i have cut it to show it here

Comment: you don't need to put the whole re cords here, just add some dummy errcords around 3-4 records per table and the desire result and that's it. it will help the readers fully understand your question.

Comment: ok w8 ill update the table...

Comment: Hi J W i have added a sample code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand you completely .. you can try this

```
SELECT movierating, COUNT(r.movieratingid) AS rank
FROM
Rating r 
INNER JOIN movie m ON r.movieratingid = m.rating_movieratingid
GROUP BY r.movierating
```

Comment: Hi i get a error that invalid use of group function upon executing your query.

Comment: edited the query trynow

Comment: Hi this works but how to check when two of them have the same rating??

Comment: @user1844638 what do you want to in that case .. ?

Answer (score 1):

This will display the rating in descending order of number of movies with that rating.

```
SELECT r.movierating, COUNT(r.movieratingid) AS rank
FROM
Rating r 
INNER JOIN movie m ON r.movieratingid = m.rating_movieratingid
GROUP BY count(r.movierating) order by 2 desc
```